# Update database field before the connections changed and turned off in android studio

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, messenger

I have a messenger app and I have an offline field in my database and want to update this field when user turn off the wifi or mobile data? like whats app and telegram?
How can I do that? I also use broadcast and a service to listen to the connectivity state change but I'm confuse to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use JobService...
Take this example:

OfflineJob class:

```
public class OfflineJob extends JobService {

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    //write your code here
    Toast.makeText(this, "job started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    schedulerService();
}
private void schedulerService() {
    
    // Your scheduler service will be called when the network is available.
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
            OfflineJob.class.getName());

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(123, component);
    // Set some other constraints
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
    // Schedule it
    mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());

}
```